# phone shows 30.38gb total when checked from the phone in settings but shows 1.7 when checked from the pc

Tags: internal-storage

my phone has 30.38gb total memory and shows 29gb free memory when i check from the phone itself but cannot install apps with large sizes and when i check from the PC it shows 1.7gb total space,what can be the correct internal storage or is it possible to fix it to its original storage displayed in the phone